# Android Studio, shortcut to launch terminal

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I can launch *Android Monitor* using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>, or *Messages Panel* using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, but there's no such code labeled on the *Terminal* panel or the *Gradle Tasks* panel.

My laptop has a small screen and I keep the *Tool Buttons* hidden to save screen space. I would really like to know the shortcut keys (if any) or any method to make custom shortcut keys since I use both the panels very often and using the mouse every time is irritating.

I have gone many lists of shortcut keys available but failed to find one.

Comment: use `Alt + F12` for terminal

Comment: @Shashanth Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From Android Studio:
open `Preferences` > `Keymap` > type "terminal" > assign the shortcut that you want.

Answer (score 11):

Along with the other answers (about defining your own shortcut):

On Mac: `fn + option + F12`

On Windows and Linux: `alt + F12`

These shortcuts come "built-in" into Android Studio and they open and close the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Did you see the number after the icons, they can be `open` or `close` with `command + number` on MAC,you can also assign a number to it, just following @Juan's method above

Answer (score 0):

*File* -> *Settings* -> *Terminal*:

[image: Screenshot]